# Playing media inside an IFrame - Ionic IOS

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-native

I'm building a hybrid app using Ionic, Cordova and Angular.
Inside the app i have two iFrames - a youtube embed and a Deezer embedd.
When running the code inside a browser or when uploading to the playstore everything works fine, but when running on an ios device I get an error from youtube and Deezer just won't play.
I think it has somehting to do with the config.xml file or some sort of a security policy but I can't put my finger on it - does anyone have an idea or came across something similar?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

in network_security_config.xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
     <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
       <trust-anchors>
           <certificates src="system" />
       </trust-anchors>
   </base-config>   
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">http://Deezer.com</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

this might solve your issue.

Comment: I will try it - can you please explain what its supposed to do?

Comment: It seems like this file is for android builds only - is there something similar for ios?

Comment: your question was related to security policy so answer that as well.  is it working?